# Split long word/string in smaller words/strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to split a word like microsoft in to mic ros oft.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? What rules are you using to split? Groups of 3 characters? 3 groups as equally sized as possible? Syllables?

Answer (score 0):

You can also split word to each letter in javascript. Hope this will help you.

```
var txt="microsoft";

txtArray=txt.split('');
txtLength=txtArray.length;

var text="";
for(var i=1;i<=txtLength;i++) {

  text+=txtArray[i-1];
  if(i%3==0) text+=" ";
}
  alert(text);
```